# Why can't Medusa turn Djinn into stone?

Tags: clash-of-the-titans-2010

Not much on this, but we are led to believe that  [Medusa](http://www.greekmythology.com/Myths/Creatures/Medusa/medusa.html) can turn anyone into stone.

> Medusa was a monster, one of the Gorgon sisters and daughter of
>   Phorkys and Keto, the children of Gaea (Earth) and Oceanus (Ocean).
>   She had the face of an ugly woman with snakes instead of hair; **anyone**
>   whoever looked into her eyes was immediately turned to stone.

Another source for a description of her, Page 30 of,  [Oh My Gods: A Modern Retelling of Greek and Roman Myths](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=umsythkvbmMC&pg=PA30&lpg=PA30&dq=Medusa%20raped%20pregnant%20by%20poseidon&source=bl&ots=GLVwzYJXOc&sig=3Hwacw4lJHA-zXEww0aaN-Dh07Q&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fhrQUrTHEOG8yAH0voGIBg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Medusa&f=false)

> Athena had always been jealous of the girl's good looks, especially
>   her lovely hair, so she turned her flowing locks into writhing snakes
>   so horrible to gaze upon that they transformed **anyone** who looked
>   at them into stone.

In Clash of the Titans [Wikia](http://clash-of-the-titans.wikia.com/wiki/Sheikh_Sulieman) it states,

> When Medusa passes he [Sheikh Sulieman] uses his **scyth** to try to
>   behead her. Medusa wraps him up in her tail and tries to turn him into
>   to stone but Sheikh only laughs, as he is immune to her power, **since
>   he is not**
>   **human.**

I am guessing that this is not canonical???

But, I can't find anything that says that Medusa can only turn humans into stone. In fact, the whole premise of the story is to get the head to kill the [Kraken](http://clash-of-the-titans.wikia.com/wiki/Kraken), which obviously is not human.

[image: Kraken]

**So, how is that the Djinn are not turned into stone by Medusa?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Io makes a reference to this earlier in the film

> **Io:** *The Gorgon Medusa. **Anything of flesh is killed by her gaze**. Her prison lies across the river Styx*

Since the Sheikh isn't made of flesh (he's apparently replaced his body parts with wood and glass), he seems to be immune to her gaze.

> *You saw Sheik Solomon, **the big wooden character**.  So, this is part of
> the world we’re creating where it’s mythology.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Director Louis Leterrier On Set Interview CLASH OF THE TITANS](http://collider.com/director-louis-leterrier-on-set-interview-clash-of-the-titans/)</sup></sub>

[image]

You may wish to note that per my earlier answer [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9729/20774), the Director makes it pretty clear that this film isn't intended to be a *faithful retelling* of the source mythos, but rather a mash-up of fantasy tropes, sword/sorcery films, Greek (and Egyptian and Sumerian) myths as well as paying lip-service to the previous film.

Comment: Is there any material on them being made of wood and glass?

Comment: @KyloRen - See edit. I recall hearing an interview where the director mentioned his glass eyes but I can't find it.

Comment: OK, thanks. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The Djinn are not human at all yet they are not of flesh anymore as one of the people in the group states "They replace their limbs with wood and black magic after battle to heal themselves." Plus with this the Djinn are from an entirely different mythology, Arabic to be exact and are akin to a genie in most traditional stories thus he is immune due to these two reasons but the second being more a myth thing as they are from two different types of culture.

Answer (score -1):

Medusa cannot turn unliving things into stone like...Kali...The Siren Figurehead or The Minoton, because there not living creatures.

Comment: The Djinn are living but they are not made of flesh, you should [edit] and clarify your answer to reflect this.

Comment: Do you have any sources to back up your statement?

Answer (score -2):

angels are made from light, the humans are made from clay. medusa turns them back into stone.
the djinn are made from smokeless fire. the djinn explodes when seeing the gorgon. he was turned back into fire and thus the explosion followed instead of a statue